# angular-cli sccs without bundling

Tags: sass, themes, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli (1.5, angular 5.0) and I want to be able to define multiple themes.  It seems one way to do this is to:

1. Define the bulk of the scss as per normal ("styleExt": "scss", and "styles": [...] .angular-cli.json)
2. Use node-sass directly (outside of angular-cli config) for the theme.scss files
3. Link to the appropriate theme.css (Either replace the default theme.css outright, or change the link href dynamically

However, I'm not sure how to make that work in conjunction with ng serve, which watches the files.  So, I was wondering if there's some way to do this through angular-cli directly.  That is, can I specify some scss files to go into the bundle, but others to generate individual css *not included in the bundle*? For example, Just generate a assets/themes/foo/theme.css from an assets/themes/foo/theme.scss ?

A  use case is that we may need multiple themes, but only distribute one to any given customer (defined to match their internal software).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional digging, I found the  [Global Styles](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles) story. If you define a style as an object with an output, it will bundle it separately, so you could swap out a default theme with another (similarily compiled) on deploy.  Or, if defined as lazy, it will not include it in the index file (index.html), and you can then define it explicitly, with an id (or unique class), and swap out the href (similar to what the [angular material](https://material.angular.io/) them switcher is doing.)